# 12.04 Can wireless network be active at login?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, login-screen

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 box that is no longer going to be used as a desktop. I would like to be able to switch it on and let it automatically connect to the wireless network so i can ssh into it if need be.

I can't find any reference to set 12.04 up like this. By default it looks like no network connections are set up at the login screen. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: You could enable autologin and also allow it to automatically connect to the wireless network in network manager. If you have a static ip then you will be able to ssh into it easily. There may be something extra that may need to be done for dynamic ips.

Comment: Yeah, that was my original plan. I was unsure if servers do the same, as if not then there must be a way to have network available at login. Unless its just wireless networks that are disabled at login.

Comment: I think wireless is enabled on the login screen itself before you actually log in. Will you be using ubuntu server edition? I'm sure you can specify which wireless network you want to connect to from the command line too.

Comment: I wasn't planning changing to server edition, i want to 'retire' the box to the basement (so to speak) and switch it on if I realise i need something from it. I want to avoid having to spend much time messing with it. I don't want it to auto login in case it gets stolen etc etc..